# How to prevent Magnific Popup from closing when submitting contact form 7?

Tags: javascript, contact-form-7, magnific-popup

I click the button and I open the popup with the form inside.

```
function openMagnificPopup() {
        $('.btn--primary').on('click', function () {
            $.magnificPopup.open({
                items: {
                    src: $('#popup-form').html(),
                    type: 'inline',
                    closeBtnInside: true,
                    modal: true,
                },
                closeOnBgClick: false,
                callbacks: {
                    open: function() {
                      jQuery('body').addClass('noscroll');
                    },
                    close: function() {
                      jQuery('body').removeClass('noscroll');
                    }
                  }
            });
        });
    }
```

I have contact form 7 inside Magnific Popup but when I click submit on contact form the popup closes because the page is refreshed.

I need to keep the popup opened when I submit the form.

Comment: So how you want to deal the situation? On click of submit button the form submits and page refreshes. Do u want to submit form without refreshing he page or what?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I think this is happening because I have the same form in the page that is when it's opened, so two forms.

Comment: you can submit the form with ajax though.